# Sudden recursive error in non-recursive script

Tags: python, ssl, package

I suddenly got an error in a script I've been using, and it makes no sense. I get it when I call a function from a package I wrote (it says it's a recursive error), but I can call that same function with the same arguments in the package main itself just fine. There are no loops involved, and there is no recursion.

I now get the error with other packages as well.

```
import play_scraper
print(play_scraper.details("com.whatsapp"))
```

This yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/wd/OneDrive - UGent/Python/test/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(play_scraper.details("com.whatsapp"))
  File "C:\Users\wd\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\play_scraper\api.py", line 22, in details
    return s.details(app_id)
  File "C:\Users\wd\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\play_scraper\scraper.py", line 292, in details
    response = send_request('GET', url)
  File "C:\Users\wd\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\play_scraper\utils.py", line 120, in send_request
    verify=verify)
  File "C:\Users\wd\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wd\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 502, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wd\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 612, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wd\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\wd\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\wd\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 345, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\wd\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 844, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\wd\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 314, in connect
    cert_reqs=resolve_cert_reqs(self.cert_reqs),
  File "C:\Users\wd\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 265, in create_urllib3_context
    context.options |= options
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 459, in options
    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 459, in options
    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 459, in options
    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
  [Previous line repeated 323 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Obviously, any sort of recursion does not occur in my two line script. My best guess: I changed something while installing an unidentified package in my 3.6.1 interpreter, as I don't get this error in 3.5. Could be one of the play_scraper requirements I installed, which are

```
beautifulsoup4 (>=4.4.1)
grequests (>=0.3.0)
lxml (>=3.6.0)
requests (>=2.9.1)
```

This is all pretty much guesswork though. Anyone have a clue as to what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same error using requests from an gunicorn gevent environment.

This is probably related to:
https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/903

According to that issue upgrading your gevent version should do the trick, although i see the same error with version 1.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

I have this error when I import `requests` before `grequests`. So, to avoid the error, import `grequests` (and modules importing `grequests`) before `requests` (and modules importing `requests`).